# 400 bad request error when using AJAX in mobile device

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using AJAX with jQuery. In desktop view AJAX working well while using with mobile devices or ipad AJAX is not working. It is showing 400 bad request error.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery.ajax({

        type: 'post',
        url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
        cache: false,
        data: {
            action: 'shows_month',
            currentDate: selectDate,
            showLimit: showvalue,
        },
        success: function(s){
            console.log(s);
            jQuery('.elements-area').html(s);
        },
        error: function(er){
            console.log(er);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you happen to be signed in in your desktop but not your other devices?

Comment: no thats not the reason @jacob. no need to sign-in

Comment: You either need to sign in or hook the Ajax for signed out users too. See the duplicate post I flagged.

Comment: @jacob i missed the spelling of 'wp_ajax_nopriv' to 'wp_ajax_noprv'. and that thing works.